# Python: Cow And Bull Game

Tags: python

*Q.Randomly generate a 4-digit number. Ask the user to guess a 4-digit number. For every digit that the user guessed correctly in the correct place, they have a “cow”. For every digit the user guessed the number in the wrong place is a “bull.”

Every time the user makes a guess, tell them how many “cows” and “bulls” they have. Once the user guesses the correct number, the game is over. Keep track of the number of guesses the user makes throughout the game and tell the user at the end.*

**Now, the problem is that I've made the program but it could generate any 4 - digit number, and that's when the problem arises. For example:

The generated number is 3568.

The user types: 3266

Then user gets 2 Cows And 2 Bulls.

But the user has no way of knowing which are the correct numbers in the number that he typed.

I want a function that can tell the user the numbers that he guessed right.
In the example, the program should tell the user that 3 and 6 are correct in the following places.**

```
import random


def compare_number(number, user_guess):
    cowbull = [0, 0]
    for i in range(len(number)):
        if number[i] == user_guess[I]:
           cowbull[1] += 1
        else:
           cowbull[0] += 1
    return cowbull


if __name__ == "__main__":
    playing = True
    number = str(random.randint(1000, 10000))
    guesses = 0

    print("Let's Play A Game Of Cows And Bulls!")
    print("I Will Generate A 4 Digit Number, And You Have To Guess The Numbers One Digit At A Time.")
    print("For Every Number I The Wrong Place, You Get A Bull. For Every Number In The Right Place, 
    You Get A Cow.")
    print("The Game Will End When You Get 4 Bulls.")
    print("Type Exit At Any Prompt To Exit!")

while playing:
    user_guess = input("Give Me The Best You Got!: ")
    if user_guess.lower() == "exit":
        break
    cowbull_count = compare_number(number, user_guess)
    guesses += 1
    print(f"You Have {cowbull_count[1]} Cows, And {cowbull_count[0]} Bulls.")

    if cowbull_count[1] == 4:
        playing = False
        print(f"You Win The Game After {guesses} Guess(es)!. The Number Was {number}.")
        break
    else:
        print(f"Your Guess Isn't Quite Right, Tyr Again!.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    import random

def compare_number(number, user_guess):
    cowbull = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    for i in range(len(number)):
        if number[i] == user_guess[i]:
           cowbull[i] += 1
    return cowbull


if __name__ == "__main__":
    playing = True
    number = str(random.randint(1000, 10000))
    guesses = 0

    print("Let's Play A Game Of Cows And Bulls!")
    print("I Will Generate A 4 Digit Number, And You Have To Guess The Numbers One Digit At A Time.")
    print("For Every Number I The Wrong Place, You Get A Bull. For Every Number In The Right Place, You Get A Cow.")
    print("The Game Will End When You Get 4 Bulls.")
    print("Type Exit At Any Prompt To Exit!")

while playing:
    user_guess = input("Give Me The Best You Got!: ")
    if user_guess.lower() == "exit":
        break
    cowbull_count = compare_number(number, user_guess)
    guesses += 1
    correct = sum(cowbull_count)
    wrong = len(number) - correct
    print(f"You Have {correct} Cows, And {wrong} Bulls.")

    if correct == 4:
        playing = False
        print(f"You Win The Game After {guesses} Guess(es)!. The Number Was {number}.")
        break
    else:
        print(f"Your Guess Isn't Quite Right, Try Again!.")
        if correct >= 1:
            print(str([user_guess[i] for i, x in enumerate(cowbull_count) if x == 1]) + " was correct!")
```

Changes made to your original code:

1. Instead of returning [numOfCorrect,numOfWrong], i returned [is 1 correct?, is 2 correct?, is 3 correct? is 4 correct?] // you need this to know which was right and which was wrong
2. the number of cows is = the number of correct which is equal to sum of 1's in cowbull_count //changed because of different return of compare_number
3. the number of bulls is = the number of wrong which is equal to number of digits - number of wrongs = len(numbers) - correct //changed because of different return of compare_number
4. if not all 4 digits were correct, show them which number they got correct // this is what you wanted

Sample run

[image: output]

Comment: Hey, It Is Working But After Three Guesses It Returns "0 Cows And 4 Bulls."  For Example, I Guess 2567 And 2 Is Correct And Then I Make Two More Guesses And  After I Make The Third Guesses It Shows "0 Cows And 4 Bulls" Even When I Am Writing "2" In My Third Guess. @Jackson

Comment: I Added @Fedortaf  Method  With Your Answer And The Problem Is Solved.

Comment: @Nelie I think that may have to do with the position of your "2". My Code is place specific so generatedNum = 2678 then 2000 return 1 cow whereas 0200 returns 0 cow even though generatedNum contains the value "2". I believe this was what you wanted. Furthermore it is only logical this way e.g. GeneratedNum = 2234 then if the user enter a 2000 will this mean he gets 2 cows? So it is logical that way. I think Fedortaf and my code is exactly the same apart from him using right_guess[i] = 1 whereas i did += 1 because i used your code. this will not affect since cowbull_count refreshes on each loop

Answer (score 1):

Add another method that return a list of positions: 4 element list, 0 if the user didn't guess a digit, 1 if he did. You can use it as you want in your function.

```
def digit_position(number, user_guess):
    right_guesses = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    for i in range(len(number)):
        if number[i] == user_guess[i]:           
           right_guesses[i] = 1
    return right_guesses
```

Comment: This Function Is Working Perfectly When I Use This With The Answer That @Jackson Has Given.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your compare number function to print the index and value of the correct number.

```
def compare_number(number, user_guess):
    cowbull = [0, 0]
    for i in range(len(number)):
        if number[i] == user_guess[I]:
           cowbull[1] += 1
           print("The number " + number[i] + " at index " + i " is correct") 
        else:
           cowbull[0] += 1
           print("The number " + number[i] + " at index " + i " is incorrect") 
    return cowbull
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Cow and Bull Game is a game in which User
# tries to guess the Secret code chosen by computer.

# We have 2 use cases i.e
# If Value in index of both User's and Computer's number are same than it is Cow.
# If Value Exists but not on same index as computer's than ita a Bull.
import random

# Following function generate a unique 4-digit number
def checkDuplication():
    r = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
    for i in r:
        if r.count(i) > 1:
            return checkDuplication()
    return r
# Following function check both number and returns Cow and Bull COUNTS.
def cowBullGame(human):
    cow_count = bull_count = 0
    for i in human:
        if i in computer:
            if human.count(i) > 1:
                print('No Repeatative Numbers Allowed!')
                return 0
            if human.index(i) == computer.index(i):         # Checking if both the value in index i are same or not
                cow_count += 1
            else:
                bull_count += 1
    print(str(cow_count)+' Cows, '+str(bull_count)+' Bulls')
    return cow_count        # Returning Cow_Count to check All Numbers are on right place.

computer = checkDuplication()
print(computer)

guesses = 1
# Infinite Loop till user gets 4 Cow_Counts
while True:
    human = str(int(input('Guess a Number :')))
    if cowBullGame(human) == 4:
        print('Game Over. You made '+str(guesses)+' guesses')
        break
    guesses += 1
```